# HOW TO: Laravel 5 - mySQL query

Tags: laravel

the situation:

I have one mySQL database and I want to get a dinstinct count of the column C_ID where the set timestamp is like the current day (e.g. 2015-08-14)

in phpMyAdmin it works fine:

> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT C_ID) FROM table WHERE touched_at LIKE '2015-08-14%'

the result is 32; but in Laravel 5 I get 320 because the distinct function does not work for me

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');

$one = DB::table('talbe')
        ->select()
        ->where('touched_at', 'like', "$date%")
        ->distinct('C_ID')
        ->count();
```

Can you please assist me with this problem?

Thanks in advance
Timo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work. Tried it in one of my projects and that produces the right answer for me.

```
$one = DB::table('talbe')
         ->where('touched_at', 'like', "$date%")
         ->count(DB::raw('distinct C_ID'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works:

```
 $date = date('Y-m-d');

  $one = DB::table('talbe')
    ->select('touched_at')
    ->where('touched_at', 'like', "$date%")
    ->distinct('C_ID')
    ->count();
```

Comment: `P_ID`, `C_ID`, `SN`, `R_MAC`, `M_MAC`, `U_MAC`, `E_MAC`, `C_MAC`, `touched_at`

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this code

```
 $date = date('Y-m-d');
 $one = DB::table('table')
     ->select(DB::raw('count(Distinct C_ID) as C_ID'))
     ->where('touched_at', 'like', "$date%")
     ->get();
```

Comment: can you show me table's dummy record because i used this query on my end and its give correct result

Comment: try this query --- DB::table('table')->where('touched_at', 'like', "$date%")->groupBy('C_ID')->count();

Comment: I need the distinct command otherwise i get all C_ID grouped seperated but i need them combined